# How do I store a JSON loop value and send it to an empty sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm pulling data from an API.

I parsed the JSON file and ran it through a loop to grab each index present within the file(14 indexes).

I believe my code stores the values in i?

So when I use log, it returns json[i][2], which logs 14 different values.(perfect)

But when I use return, it only returns 1 value into my google sheet.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
function myKlines(){
 var url='https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=ADAUSDT&interval=1d&limit=14'
 var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
 var json = JSON.parse(source)
  for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
   var loop = json[i][2];
   Logger.log(loop);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By function `=myKlines(A1)`

```
function myKlines(code){
 var url='https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol='+code+'&interval=1d&limit=14'
 var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
 var json = JSON.parse(source)
 for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++){json[i][0] = new Date(json[i][0])}
 return json
}
```

for date/high/low/close

```
function myKlinesExtract(code){
 var url='https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol='+code+'&interval=1d&limit=14'
 var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
 var json = JSON.parse(source)
 var result = []
 result.push(['Date','High','Low','Close'])
 for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
  result.push([new Date(json[i][0]),json[i][2],json[i][3],json[i][4]])
 }
 return result
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JDT1TSwbAVcMrhWEHGH8jprt0u_gAnRqjY_W7W7SaQ4/copy

Comment: Awesome! I'm learning a lot! Now, this is a problem I've been coming across when trying to get this function just right. Everything here is perfect, but how can I only print out the high, low, close, and date, excluding everything else? When I attempt to, it only prints out one result instead of all 14. Thank you again!

Comment: take a new copy, I updated my answer - be careful not to get banned a bit because of too many requests

Answer (score 0):

As you have it now, you are iterating through the variable json, but you aren't doing anything with the data.

To save the data from the loop, you need to put each iteration into an array or an object.

To make it easy, here it is with an array:

```
function myKlines(){
  var url='https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=ADAUSDT&interval=1d&limit=14'
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var json = JSON.parse(source)
         
  var output = []; //declaring an empty array
        
  for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
    var loop = json[i][2];
    Logger.log(loop);
    // add the contents of this iteration to the output array     
    output.push(loop);
  }
  Logger.log(output);
        
  // send the output to a function to paste the data into your sheet.
  // you could also just replace below with the paste code
  pasteOutput(output);
}
```

Next, to paste it into a sheet, you need to build the range it will go into.  I am guessing you want to paste the 14 indexes into different cells.  Here is the 14 cells in a single column:

```
function pasteOutput(output){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('your sheet name');
      
  // get how many items there are in your array
  var outputLength = output.length;
      
  // this gets a range that starts at row 1, col 1, and has as many rows 
  //as your array has items, and is 1 column wide
  var pasteRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,outputLength,1);
    
  /*
    Sheets takes values as a 2 dimensional array with 
    the inner array being a row, and the items inside the inner array the columns like this:  
    [[row1col1, row1col2, row1col3],[row2col1, row2col2, row2col3],[row3col1, row3col2, row3col3],...]
  */
    
  // this statement  will take each item in the output array, 
  //make it an array of one thing, and add that to the pasteArray  
  var pasteArray = output.forEach(item => pasteArray.push([item]));
    
  pasteRange.setValues(pasteArray);
}
```

To put the cells in a single row, omit the pasteArray line, and change your pasteRange to (1,1,1 outputLength)

Answer (score 0):

By this way, you will get all datas at once in sheet ADAUSDT

```
function myKlinesAll(){
 var url='https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=ADAUSDT&interval=1d&limit=14'
 var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
 var json = JSON.parse(source)
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('ADAUSDT')
 var headers = ["Open time","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Close time","Quote asset volume","Number of trades","Taker buy base asset volume","Taker buy quote asset volume","Ignore"]
 for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++){json[i][0] = new Date(json[i][0])}
 sheet.getRange(1,1,1,headers.length).setValues([headers])
 sheet.getRange(2,1,json.length,json[0].length).setValues(json)
}
```

By this way, you will retrieve only column#2 (High)

```
function myKlines(){
 var url='https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=ADAUSDT&interval=1d&limit=14'
 var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
 var json = JSON.parse(source)
 var result = []
 result.push(['Date','High'])
 for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
  result.push([new Date(json[i][0]),json[i][2]])
 }
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('ADAUSDT')
 sheet.getRange(1,18,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result)
}
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick nicely, thank you. If I may ask for one more thing, is there a way to create a date logger that inputs the corresponding date for these values? Thanks again!

Comment: You will have then to transform epoch to local time by `new Date(json[i][0])` answer updated

Comment: Wow okay. I'm a complete noob and it's amazing how you can figure it out so easily. One more thing: Is there a way to call the function from a cell "=myKlines()" with this code? If not, how could I make the "symbol=ADAUSD" user input? Thanks